# Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to modify a stored procedure ( adding a new column in select statement) but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'vwPersonSearch' because it is not full-text indexed.
```

When I try to create a Full text index on view 'vwPersonSearch' using SQL server 2008 R 2 management studio, I am getting this error:

A unique column must be defined on this table/view.

Please suggest solution to it

Comment: Please specify exact query and structure of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may [alter a column](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/unique.htm) to be `unique` if that's one that could be or add an `id` of some sort to do that part.

Answer (score 1):

To create a full text index, you must specify a key index, which must be a unique, single-key, non-nullable column. An integer column type is recommended for best performance.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx for more details.